# C++ members selection operators

Tags: c++, selection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between the dot (.) operator and ->  in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c)

C++ has the following member selection operators: `.` and `->`.

What is the *main* difference between them?

Thanks.

Comment: this question has already been asked here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c

Comment: That question is also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221346/what-is-the-arrow-operator-synonym-for-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is used with non-pointers, while `->` is used with pointers, to access members!

```
Sample s;
Sample *pS = new Sample();

s.f() ;  //call function using non-pointer object
pS->f(); //call the same function, using pointer to object
```

`.` cannot be overloaded, while `->` can be overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

`pointer2object->member()` 
is equal to 
`(*pointer2object).member()`
and is made for more convinience, as I suppose.

Comment: Not in C++, there they can mean different things.

Comment: Provide an example, please. I always thought about -> in the way above.

Comment: You can overload the dereference operator and you can overload `->`, if you do it in a way that they disagree, your two ways aren't equal.