# C++ arrow operator equivelence

Tags: c++, pointers

The posts [What can I use instead of the arrow operator, `->`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221346/what-can-i-use-instead-of-the-arrow-operator)
and [Arrow operator (->) usage in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c)
state

> The following two expressions are equivalent:
>
> ```
> x->y
> (*x).y
> ```

But this does not appear to always be true when taken as a mathematical equivalence.

Why does g++ throw an error when replacing

```
a->b->c
```

with

```
a->(*b).c
```

?

It seems the above equivalence is not *always* replaceable. Therefore, I think the term "equivalent" is a bit misleading.

Also, I am not referring to any sort of overloading in this question.

Comment: By the way, you’re wrong in this particular regard (see answers) but it’s true in general that `a->b` and `(*a).b` are *not* necessarily equivalent, since `->` and `*` can be overloaded for your own classes. They *are* completely equivalent when `a` is of pointer type, however (or when `operator ->` and `operator *` are overloaded correctly).

Comment: Konrad, my point is we have to be careful about the term "completely equivalent". When I read that phrase, it reads "any instance of the first can be replaced with the second". It seems that in this case, equivalence is dependent upon the order of operations.

Comment: They *are* completely equivalent. But you still need to obey the rules of precedence when doing replacements. You cannot just do textual replacements. After all, in mathematics “x + x” and “2 * x” are completely equivalent (they are equal for all values of x), yet when you ignore the rules of mathematics and replace the first by the second in the mathematical expression “x + x / 2” you get a wrong result (because x + x / 2 ≠ 2 * x / 2).

Comment: But (x + x) / 2 is equivalent. However, a->((*b).c) also seems to fail.

Comment: Because now you’re violating the grammar rules of C++. `->` must be followed by an identifier, not an expression. That’s still the same as in mathematics. Otherwise you get joke equations like this one: http://i.imgur.com/JLPF2.jpg

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've got the associativity rules wrong. `a->b->c` is `(a->b)->c`, not `a->(b->c)`, so it becomes `(*(a->b)).c` (and then `(*((*a).b)).c`).

Answer (score 8):

Because you're not replacing the operators correctly. It should be:

```
(*(a->b)).c
```

You're treating your expression as `a->(b->c)` when you should be treating it as `(a->b)->c`

Answer (score 2):

You're doing the replacement incorrectly.

`a->b->c` is equivalent to `(*(a->b)).c`.

`a->(*b).c` doesn't make sense for a number of reasons. `b` is not a pointer you can dereference (the pointer is `a->b`). Additionally, even if it were, using the dereferenced pointer in the context of a field of `a` would not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seeing is an issue with the precendence of the different operators, you should use: `(*(x->y)).z` (The operands to the second `->` are `(x->y)` and `z`). But that has already been answered before.

It is important to note, however, that the equivalence is only true for *pointers*, and that the properties of both operators when overloaded are completely different. The `operator->` has very strange semantics in the language, in the sense that it does not represent a single operation, but can represent multiple applications of `operator->` until the overloaded operator yields a raw pointer, at which point it will perform one last application that is equivalent to dereference plus access (i.e. only for this last application, `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a)->b`.)