# Expression must have class type but it has type "*shape"

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to create a vector as show below:

```
std::vector<double> dimensions_data_vec{input_shape_pointer.get_dimensions()};
```

In this code, `input_shape_pointer` is a pointer to a shape such as a rectangle. A shape has dimensions associated with it, eg. length and width. I now have to create another, separate class which takes a pointer to a shape and accesses its dimensions. To do this I am using the code snippet.

The `get_dimensions()` function is a part of the shape class and returns the dimensions of a shape in a vector which has a type `double`.

My code issues the error

> Expression must have class type but it has type "*shape" (please note the asterisk here)

My question is, how do I have `get_dimensions()` work on the shape before the vector is initialised so that there is no mismatch, and `dimensions_data_vec` just takes in the vector double of shape dimensions? I think there may be an issue with initializing a vector with another vector anyway, but I want to work on one problem at a time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[What can I use instead of the arrow operator, `->`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/221346/90527)", "[What is the difference between the dot (.) operator and -> in C++?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/90527)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `input_shape_pointer` is a *pointer* to a `shape` then use `->` instead of `.`. For example, the expression

```
input_shape_pointer.get_dimensions()
```

should be replaced by:

```
input_shape_pointer->get_dimensions()
```

Note the use of `->` instead of `.` in the above expression

Comment: Thank you very much, my error has now gone. However, I am now getting a segmentation fault with get_dimensions which looks like.                        
      std::vector<double>/get_dimensions(shape shape_ptr){
        std::vector<double> dim_vec;
        for(int i{0}; i<2; i++){
            dim_vec.push_back(dimensions_data[i]);
        }
        return dim_vec;
      }                                                                                                                                                 where dimensions_data contains the dimensions in a double array.

Comment: @purecobalt Make sure that the pointer `input_shape_pointer` is not uninitialized before dereferencing it. That is, make sure that the pointer is pointing to some `shape` object before dereferencing it. Otherwise, you'll have undefined behavior which may result in a crash.

Comment: I've double checked this but haven't dereferenced it. I think the seg fault is from dimensions_data[i] but can't see why this would be the case as I initialise that array with size 3.

Comment: @purecobalt You've dereferenced the pointer `input_shape_pointer` when you wrote: `input_shape_pointer->get_dimensions()`. So before writing the expression `input_shape_pointer->get_dimensions()` make sure(if not already) that `input_shape_pointer` is pointing to some `shape` object. If this still doesn't solve the problem, you can ask your follow up question as a separate question with sufficient details given in that question.

Comment: Please may you explain how I go about doing this? My only idea is to do it in the main code.

Comment: @purecobalt For example, you could do something like: `shape s; s.setDimensions(5,6); shape* input_shape_pointer = &s; std::vector<double> dimensions_data_vec{input_shape_pointer->get_dimensions()};`. Since you've not given enough information in the question for us to debug, we can't say exactly where the problem is. In the above given snippet, i have made sure that `input_shape_pointer` points to object `s`. Similarly, you also have to make sure the same.